# cannot display image using printf

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, printf

I have the following snippet for calling post author, time and categories

```
<?php
    printf( __( '<span>%s</span> by %s in %s', 'xxxx' ),
        get_the_time( 'M j' ),
        et_get_the_author_posts_link(),
        get_the_category_list( ', ' )
    );
```

?>

I would like to replace the "by" (before author) and "in" (befor categories) with an image

I have tried this:

```
'<span>%s</span> <img src="by.png"> %s <img src="in.png"> %s', 'xxxx'
```

and this:

```
$img = '<img src="/images/myimage.png" alt="Some Image" />';
printf( __( '<span>%s</span> %s %s in %s', 'xxxx' ),
    get_the_time( 'M j' )
    $img,
    et_get_the_author_posts_link(),
    get_the_category_list( ', ' )
);
```

This one prints out the alt of the image before the author but not the image.

Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`printf` fills in the arguments in the order you specify them. If you want the `<img>` to show up inside the `<span>` then you'll have to list the image first in the arguments:

```
printf('format string here', $img, get_the_time('M j'), etc...
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- swap these two
```

e.g.

```
printf('%s %s %s', $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
        ^------------^
            ^---------------^
               ^-------------------^
```

If you mess around with the argument order, e.g. `$arg3, $arg2, $arg1`, then they'll be printed in that order...

Comment: Thank for the reply, i don't need to show the image in the '<span>' the span used his for to style the time only. I am getting a broken image link. I think the problem is in `<img src="/images/myimage.png" alt="Some Image" />` i need to call it from the theme directory...any advice how to do so within the printf. thanks